# Azure RedHat VM returns SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate error on yum install

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I am getting the below error while trying to install a package in my redhat server hosted in Azure.

```
Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://rhui-2.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]
```

Please help me fix this.

Thanks and Regards

Rohit R

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you created your redhat VM in azure you chose bring your license (superscription). if yes then you need to execute commands in the following links https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/redhat/byos if not (you asked Azure to use their own superscription ) you can file a ticket with their support to register this VM for you.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! But we are not using byos in our infrastructure. We are currently using azure repositories.

Comment: @rohitpillai can you use yum? if yes then try to use `yum install ca-certificates`